# How to compare the value in the list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

List:
        Bag = [
            (a, 1, 2),
            (b, 2, 3),
            (c, 3, 4)],

I want to compare the result of 1*2 in list a, 2*3 in list b, and 3*4 in list c.
And sort the result and output, how to do that in PROLOG?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `sort/2`:

```
?- findall([Result, Name], 
        (member((Name, A, B), [(a, 3, 2), (b, 1, 3), (c, 3, 4)]),
         Result is A*B),Output), 
   sort(Output, SOutput).

SOutput = [[2, a], [6, b], [12, c]].
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that this needs another answer, but a DCG which relates a list of terms such as `(c,3,4)` as 'input' with a list of pairs `c-12` as 'output' is:

```
task([])       --> [].
task([A-B|Ls]) --> [(A, X,Y)], {B is X*Y}, task(Ls).
```

Then sort/4-ing the pairs by the value:

```
?- Bag = [(a, 1, 2), (b, 2, 3), (c, 3, 4)],
   phrase(task(_Pairs), Bag),
   sort(1, @>=, _Pairs, Result).

Result = [c-12, b-6, a-2]
```